# why is the geom_errorbar only giving me little lines in the middle of my plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I have an issue when using geom_errorbar. All i get is little lines in the middle ,rather than the whole range?!

```
gd <- data_long %>% 
  group_by(ISItime, FIRST_cat) %>% 
  summarise(mean_ISI= mean(ISIscore, na.rm = TRUE), 
            sd_ISI= sd(ISIscore, na.rm = TRUE))
    
    
gd<- gd %>% 
  mutate(ymax = mean_ISI + sd_ISI, ymin = mean_ISI - sd_ISI)
```

```
ggplot(gd, aes(x = ISItime, y = mean_ISI, group= FIRST_cat, color= FIRST_cat)) +
  geom_line (alpha= 0.9, size = 2) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line()+
  geom_errorbar( aes(x=ISItime, ymin=mean_ISI-sd_ISI, ymax=mean_ISI+sd_ISI), width=0.6, 
                 colour="orange", alpha=0.9, size=.3, position=position_dodge(.3))+
  ylim(c(2,12))+ labs(x="Month", y="Mean ISI Score") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Pre-Study ISI","T0","T1","T2","T3",
                            "T4","T5","T6","T7","T8","T9",
                            "T10","T11","T12")) +
  labs(x = "Timepoint")
```

[image]

If anyone can help, i would be so grateful. I  am so confused at what i have done wrong, and why i am not getting proper error bars.
Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to replace `ylim(2, 12)` with `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2, 12))`. The difference is that the first removes out of bounds values whereas the second clips out of bounds values.